# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

After update with the latest Android support library 23.1 i get this error

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0

I tried all combination of 23.+ and 23.1.0 and 23.1.+ etc. How to make it run properly?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ua.g.tfinder"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: After updated the sdk-manager try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 31):

The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository.

**Step 1:** Open the build.gradle file of your project.

**Step 2:** Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" url in it.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for old version of libraries thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I ran into the same problem today. Although the SDK Manager marked a few libraries as installed, investigating the location of the files showed me the correct folder structure, without any files in them.

For example, checking out the location of 23.1.0 appcompat-v7 on my Mac:
.../sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7
turned out to be an empty folder.

I suspect the update I ran minutes before went wrong somehow.

**What solved it for me:**

1. in Android Studio, open Appearance and Behaviour -> System Settings -> SDK Manager
2. under tab "SDK Tools" un-check the libraries causing problems
3. click "apply" to uninstall them
4. re-check the same libraries
5. click "apply" to reinstall them
6. close SDK Manager and run Gradle sync / build

Comment: There is no Android tab under Tools in Android Studio 3.0.1. Please precise your version when submitting this kind of answer

Comment: @EmilKorngold androidSDK is under appearance and behavior > system Settings

Answer (score 14):

Had to add "Android Support Repository" from SDK Manager.

Answer (score 11):

As you already have `v7` dependency added in your gradle file no need to add dependency for `v4` because it is already included in `v7` library.

gradle file should looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ua.guru.lvivflatfinder"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

.......

1. (build.gradle (MOdule.app)
2. `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'`

Comment: now i get Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
Install Repository and sync project

Comment: but i already installed latest Android support library 23.1 and support repo 24

Comment: please double check it because my app is working fine with these dependencies http://i.imgur.com/fFErM1h.png?1

Comment: In my case just commenting that support library was enough.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, opening SDK manager and installing `Local Maven Repository for Support Libraries` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Project Structure then select Dependencies tab and remove com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Gradle sync / build
2. implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

ready and go!

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem, was trying to change versions and so on. Did not work for me. Only after I changed the version and restarted Studio it started to work. Probably gradle doesn't sync that normaly while you don't restart Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to build the app while being OFFLINE. After connecting to the internet it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

he support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository.

Step 1: Open the build.gradle file of your project and add the following dependencies.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```