# I'm having error Trying to Build my apk : failed to resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio

This is my build gradle, any help fixing this error? I am also having a error :

> failed resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:14.0.4

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Kreatech.handje"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    //===============
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.6.0.jar')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:14.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file of Appliaction level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185086/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v423-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

> To add a Support Library to your application project:
>
> Open the build.gradle file for your application. Make sure that the
>   repositories section includes a maven section with the
>   "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works now , im getting this following error   ,,Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in build.gradle file of Application level

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it worked but now im having 6Errors :: Error:(3, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background').

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a gradle dependency that required an old version of the support library, so the build was deciding to use the old version.

I found this out by running a "Gradle dependency report" described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/34935):

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies \
  --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath >& foo.txt
```

I then updated the old dependency, and this started to work.